# Remove old revisions from local git repository, but not from remote

Tags: git

I'm working on a project with more than a year of history, and a total size (git folder and working directory) of more than 25 GB.

I reckon that most of this comes from old versions of files, almost all of which are no longer needed. So I want to save space by removing revisions older than a month from my local git repository, but I explicitly **don't** want to delete the commits permanently, or do anything that requires collaborators to take action. Ideally, I would still be able to see commit messages and authors, but if I wanted to see the actual changes or checkout these commits I would have to download them again. I believe this data makes up the majority of the git folder.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Alternatively, what are some ways I can reduce the size of my .git folder without permanently deleting data?

Comment: You can have only recent commits in local while keeping the while history in remote, that is called a "shallow" clone. There are many questions about it already, so maybe check then it and ask again if you need more specific help.

Comment: @tkruse I will try re-cloning the project with a low depth, that sounds like what I need. But I won't be able to get back to this until tomorrow.

Comment: This significantly reduced the size of the .git folder.